Is $\mathbb{F}_{p^r}/(X^{p^r}-X)$ a Principal Ideal Domain?
I am studying a field $\left(\mathbb{F}_{p^r},+,\cdot\right)$ of order $p^r$ such that p is a prime number and $r$ is a strictly positive natural number. Is the quotient ring
$$\frac{\mathbb{F}_{p^r}[X]}{(X^{p^r}-X)}$$
a principal ideal domain?
Any help is appreciated.

It's not a domain. But every quotient $F[x]/p(x)$, $F$ a field, is a principal ideal ring.

It is not a domain, since $X(X^{p^r-1}-1)=0$ in your quotient ring. But as @Qiaochu Yuan said, it is a principal ideal ring. This is because $F_p[X]$ is a PID.
